# Find the length of the longest palindrome in a given string

Tags: javascript

Find the length of the longest substring in the given string s that is the same in reverse.
As an example, if the input was “I like racecars that go fast”, the substring (racecar) length would be 7.
If the length of the input string is 0, return value must be 0.

**Example:**

```
"a" -> 1 
"aab" -> 2  
"abcde" -> 1
"zzbaabcd" -> 4
"" -> 0
```

**The test cases that need to work:**

```
Test.assertEquals(longestPalindrome("a"), 1)
Test.assertEquals(longestPalindrome("aa"), 2)
Test.assertEquals(longestPalindrome("baa"),3)
Test.assertEquals(longestPalindrome("aab"), 3)
Test.assertNotEquals(longestPalindrome("zyabyz"), 6, "Are you sure that is a palindrome?")
Test.assertEquals(longestPalindrome("baabcd"), 4)
Test.assertEquals(longestPalindrome("baablkj12345432133d"), 9)
```

**My code so far:**

```
  longestPalindrome=function(s){
    var res = s.split(" ");
    var sortArr = res.sort(function(a,b){return b.length - a.length});

    var res = (sortArr[0]);
    var ress = res.length;
    return ress;
    }
```

Why doesn't this work please?

Comment: Because it's not attempting to find any palindromes at all? There's nothing here to debug - are you asking for someone to write *all* of the palindrome detection?

Comment: You are on the right direction.. Once you have sortArr, loop over each of the entries, and find out which one is palindrome. Return the length for the first positive case.

Comment: @tanjir What if there's a multiple-word palindrome? Or a palindrome *within* a word, like the "baabcd" example above? Neither will be listed in `sortArr`

Comment: The way you can detect palindrome is by comparing the first and last letters until you have compared all the letters (for even numbers of letters) or have the middle one left (for odd number of letters)

Comment: I was going to ask "Who did this terrible thing to you?" but then I thought you might just be doing it for fun...